Rails cors issue with JS files and URL rewrite
In my root domain (example.com), I entered a rewrite rule using Render UI so that users visiting example.com/library will see the application hosted on library.example.com.

Now, when visiting example.com/library, the JS is not loaded because of a CORS error. Instead, the CSS is loaded successfully.

I use Rails importmap, if relevant.
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "https://library.example.com/assets/application-ec9fb8976583666f9882e99ffe94f0391fc9ac4f1a32034d128201c87ac33ca3.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "https://library.example.com/assets/turbo.min-dfd93b3092d1d0ff56557294538d069bdbb28977d3987cb39bc0dd892f32fc57.js",
    "posthog-js": "https://library.example.com/assets/posthog-js-27c6009e7053c1cc4ca4881a8510159e64330186618212ecf07859f877b74651.js",
    "posthog-custom": "https://library.example.com/assets/src/posthog-e818ed81c53c6838d2ee7e8efc4f6faaf02a31bc3ea7e95fe0b56eacbdd4c025.js",
    "video-custom": "https://library.example.com/assets/src/video-eefb06ba48956b0b5d08542119b3782b256b09daf694e20c8de3164ca020c541.js"
  }
}</script>

This is the full URL of a JS file:
GET https://library.example.com/assets/application-ec9fb8976583666f9882e99ffe94f0391fc9ac4f1a32034d128201c87ac33ca3.js
Request headers

:authority: library.example.com
:method: GET
:path: /assets/applicationec9fb8976583666f9882e99ffe94f0391fc9ac4f1a32034d128201c87ac33ca3.js
:scheme: https
accept: /
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language: it
cache-control: no-cache
dnt: 1
origin: https://www.example.com
pragma: no-cache
priority: u=1
referer: https://www.example.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
sec-fetch-dest: script
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Response headers

age: 12
cache-control: public, max-age=14400
cf-cache-status: HIT
cf-ray: m8c589566aaca599b-MXP
content-encoding: mgzip
content-type: application/javascript
date: Thu, 19 Sep 2024 09:35:04 GMT
etag: W/"66e18820-b8"
expires: Thu, 19 Sep 2024 13:35:04 GMT
last-modified: Wed, 11 Sep 2024 12:08:00 GMT
server: cloudflare
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by: cloud66

I have added this on the Ruby on Rails app hosted on library.example.com.
/config/application.rb
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do

      allow do
        origins 'https://www.example.com','https://example.com'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
      end

end

but isn't working.
I expect no errors in dev console and I must be able to visit example.com/library and load the page served from library.example.com with all CSS and JS.

I know they are not the same. I use a Rewrite rule from the root domain to transform requests from www.example/library to library.example.com

Can you post the rewrite rule?

@engineersmnky It's standard rewrite rule using the Render UI dashboard. I've added a few screenshots.

Is there a CSP configured?

SOLVED. After a few days, here all the settings needed to make it work.
Cloudflare
Bot flight mode was blocking the request. So, I solved with a WAF Rule
Cloudflare > Security > WAF

IF hostname=library.example.com THEN skip All Super Bot Fight Mode Rules
IF path=/library THEN skip All Super Bot Fight Mode Rules

Render
Order is important. Be sure to add a rewrite rule for your assets.

CLOUD66

Ruby on Rails
/app/config/enviroment/production.rb
  config.asset_host = "https://www.example.com/library"
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "https://www.example.com" }
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: "https://www.example.com" }

config/routes.rb
resources :my_resource, only: [:index], path: '/library' do

app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def default_url_options
    { host: Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] }
  end
end


This behavior happens with rack::cors when the requests's origin header string doesn't match perfectly, which is why the access-control-allow-origin header is missing in the server response, causing the CORS error.
Reading above, it appears there are three proxies in front. To find the offending proxy, work backwards, by get this working locally (editing your /etc/hosts file), then try with cloud66 locally, then render.com, and then adding cloudflare.
